# How to color a patch file generated from git

Tags: linux, git

I have a file.patch file generated from someone else. I want to review the patch file, but I would like to be able to apply my own git color config to the file.

I may not currently be in a git project directory and I may not even know what repo the patch file came from, but I just want to see basically context/additions/deletions colored with my normal git colors.

I'm looking for a pipeline solution rather than some external library. Something like:
`git --please-color-this file.patch | less`

Comment: Your best bet would just be to turn the patch into a commit. (Commits are cheap.) But of course this requires that you have the repository...

Comment: I am on an oooolllld server at the minute, trying to colorize `bzr diff` output. So old I cannot `apt install colordiff` so Goldfish Tim's answer was the right one for me! Recommend marking as answer :) Thanks for asking this so I could find Tim's awesome answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
colordiff < file.patch | less -R
```

The 'less' command is optional but I find it useful, e.g. for scrolling, searching.

Comment: You can also use `diff --color` since diff 3.5 as per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196565/how-to-color-diff-output) answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim for this. Just open the file with `vim file.patch`

If you are worried about changing the file then use the `-M` read-only flag `vim -M file.patch`

If you are trying to view it when reading from a pipe, you can tell vim to read from STDIN by using a `-` as the file name.

`diff -u file_a.py file_b.py | vim -M -`

Comment: AMAAAAAZING ANSWER. Thank you so much. No idea why this isn't marked as correct everywhere it may be asked. Lol. Nice stuff Tim "Goldfish" Hughes. 

Answer (score 0):

`less` is not the program you're looking for, the colors are not stored in the file and `less` doesn't understand the diff format. Instead, use a tool that understands the diff format, for instance text editors such as `vscode` or `vim`. The best program is the program you currently use for merge conflicts.

Comment: `less` is the current and default program used for showing diffs as seen by `git diff`.